# Why isn't the primary key incrementing ON DUPLICATE?

Tags: mysql

I have the following TEACHER table that has the following schema:

```
create table TEACHER
(
   TEACHERID            int not null auto_increment,
   FIRST_NAME           varchar(20) not null,
   SURNAME              varchar(20) not null,
   primary key (TEACHERID)
);
```

I have multiple inserts with the same first name and surname of teacher that I wish to omit. The schema is given and I don't plan on modifying it.

I try to execute dynamically in my program the following query but the TEACHERID is not incrementing, actually no new fields with new first name and last name are added, there is only one field that is constantly being updated.

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO TEACHER set ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FirstName = ?, LastName = ?'
```

with the `?` are defined as follows: `values: [set, professor.name, professor.sname ]`
where a set is defined as follows:

```
set = {
         FirstName: professor.name,
         LastName: professor.sname
       }
```

How do I get the primary key to increment on each duplicate, without actually adding that duplicate?

Thank you

Comment: You do not have any unique key (except the primary) you should not get duplicate situation ever

Comment: @Mojtaba when i execute the query, no fields are added, there is only one field that is constantly being updated -- question updated

Comment: As I see, your format is not correct. Look at here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: However, As you do not have unique key, you don't need to to put ON DUPLICATE condition.
Just insert

Comment: @axiac TEACHERID is automatically generated by mysql

Comment: In which universe is your query supposed to hit a unique constraint in order to follow up with `ON DUPLICATE KEY`? It sure isn't this universe.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that behavior cause you are using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. If you really want to insert the duplicate record then just perform a `INSERT` statement like

```
INSERT INTO TEACHER VALUES('test','test')
```

> How do I get the primary key to increment on each duplicate, without
>   actually adding that duplicate?

Sorry that's not possible at-least with `auto increment`. You will then have to have your own primary key and on every insert do some manipulation through a `before insert` trigger. Something like

```
create table TEACHER
(
   TEACHERID int not null primary key,

create trigger trg_binsert
on TEACHER before insert
for each row
begin
if(new.FIRST_NAME = FIRST_NAME and new.SURNAME = SURNAME)
update TEACHER 
SET TEACHERID = TEACHERID + 1
WHERE new.FIRST_NAME = FIRST_NAME 
and new.SURNAME = SURNAME;
end if
end
```

Though, not sure why you want to do that and won't recommend as well.

Comment: I dont want to insert the duplicate values, I want one instance of each duplicate value. That is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this with a query on each insert?

Comment: @Predator44, certainly NO.

Comment: So, add a unique key includes FIRST_NAME and SURNAME